# Replace url() relative path with full domain in css files

Tags: css, bash, sed

I'd like to run a script on release that replaces all url() declarations in a css file with the full domain path, because images are hosted on a static web server.

Example

```
Current:  background-image: url(/images/menu.gif);
Desired:  background-image: url(http://example.com/images/menu.gif);
Current:  background-image: url('/images/menu.gif');
Desired:  background-image: url('http://example.com/images/menu.gif');
Current:  background-image: url("/images/menu.gif");
Desired:  background-image: url("http://example.com/images/menu.gif");
```

I have concocted a bash script using sed to do just that, but it does not handle url with quotes url(''), or urls that already have a full path.

```
 STATIC_HOST="http://example.com"
 sed -i '' "s|url(\([^)]*\)|url($STATIC_HOST\1|g" main.css
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore ones that already have the full path?

Comment: Yes, but most importantly I need to be able to handle the single and double quote cases. Updated test cases above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this

```
sed "s|\(url(['\"]\?\)\(/[^)]*\)|\1$STATIC_HOST\2|g" main.css
```

Put the -i option only when you are sure the result is what you were
looking for.

Comment: Remove the `url(` in the replacement text and Ill switch from -1 to +1

Comment: Update `\\(url('\?\\)` to `\\(url(['\"]\?\\)` so your script meets the OP's new requirements.  Didn't feel like it was right to answer jack you for such a small change.

Comment: This should work fine; I have escaped the double quote because otherwise the shell would have interpretated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
|url\(['\"]?([^'\":)]+)['\"]?\)|url($STATIC_HOST\1)|g
```

where the colon will prevent "http://..." like urls

Comment: You should add the comment that you need GNU sed with the '-r` option for your ERE's to work properly